# Set <div> background color on load, then change between 3 colors when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-color, onload

I am trying to set the background color of a div upon page load to blue.  Then I want to cycle through 3 different colors (red, yellow, and green) when clicked and have the selected color remain.  Below is my sample code.  You can see the first two do nothing when clicked due to setting the blue color on load.  I didn't load the 3rd div to blue on load to show how I want the behavior to act once clicked.  Any help is appreciated.

```js
    function colorload() {
    
        var element = document.getElementById("day1");
        element.style.backgroundColor = "blue";    
    
        var element = document.getElementById("day2");
        element.style.backgroundColor = "blue";    
     
    }
    
    function changeColor(e, numb) {
        var color = e.className;
        e.className = (color == 'red') ? 'amber' : 
                      (color == 'amber') ? 'green' : 
                      (color == 'green') ? 'red' : 
                      'undefined'; 
    
    }
```

```css
    <style onload="colorload()">
    .red {background-color:red;}
    .amber {background-color:yellow;}
    .green {background-color:green;}
    
    
    div {
        width:200px;
        height:100px;
        margin:50px;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        line-height: 90px;
        font-weight:bold;
        user-select: none;
        cursor:pointer;
        }
</style>
```

```html
  
    
    <html>
        <body>
            <div class="red" id="day1" onclick="changeColor(this, 1)">One</div>
            <div class="green" id="day2" onclick="changeColor(this, 2)">Two</div>
            <div class="amber" id="day3" onclick="changeColor(this, 3)">Three</div>
        </body>    
    </html>
```

Comment: Hello @Genuis and welcome to StackOverflow, to be honest i did not understand exactly the need, but through what i understood is that you want to change the background of your page by the same color clicked ? it would be nice if you can reformulate the hole post by giving concrete examples if needed . i tried [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/s8gea9nr/9/) for you but i'm not sure about the need

Comment: hey, please here:  https://truerootcause.com/testsql/loada.php   i am trying to change the background of the boxes not the page

Comment: i want to load the boxes as blue, but then change the box color when clicked b/t red, green, and yellow

Comment: in my example, box three is the behavior I want however I need to load box three as blue upon page load

Comment: Hi again @genuis, so from what i read i understand this process: first step, the three box are blue, whenever i click on a box , i should see the next color (which is red) if i click again on the same box i should have green and so on.. right? if is this is the case, what if we reached the yellow, should we return to blue or red ? those are details we must know so we can help you with the right correction :)

Comment: you are correct:  first step, the three boxes are blue, whenever you click on a box, you should see the next color (which is red), if you click again on the same box you should have green and so on, when you reach yellow you return to red

Comment: hello @genuis, thank you for your answers, i made an answer below you can check it, if there is some issues or something wrong you can pass a comment we will update the answer to your needs. good luck

Answer (score 0):

i made an update to your **html** and **JS** codes,
i used in this example `.style`  instead of css classes, if you are interested on using classes you can refer to my comments and [this link on mdn](https://jsfiddle.net/o29uvd8t/1/) it's pretty simple.

**Html file**

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <!-- i used .btn class and data-col to play with indexes -->
        <div class="btn" id="day1" data-col="0" onclick="changeColor(event)">One</div>
        <div class="btn" id="day2" data-col="0" onclick="changeColor(event)">Two</div>
        <div class="btn" id="day3" data-col="0" onclick="changeColor(event)">Three</div>
    </body>    
</html>
```

**Js file**

```js
let divs;
let colors = ['blue', 'red', 'green' , 'yellow'];

// when loading the page, we are catching all divs having the class "btn"
// to render it with Blue background
document.body.onload = function() {
    divs = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
    divs.forEach(btn => {
       const selectedColorIndex = btn.dataset.col;
       btn.style = 'background:'+colors[selectedColorIndex];
    });
};


function changeColor(e) {
    // catch the clicked div which passed by the "event" value in the html file
    let divElement = e.target;

    // get data-col value and convert it to number with (+)
    const selectedColorIndex = +divElement.dataset.col;

    // check if we have a next color or get the red index
    const nextSelectedColor =  selectedColorIndex +1 >= colors.length?1:selectedColorIndex+1;

    // update data-col with the next new color index to conserve the iteration (loop)
    divElement.dataset.col = nextSelectedColor;

  // if you want to use classes you can access with 
  // .classList.add(..) and .classList.remove(..) OR 
  // .classList.toggle(..)
    divElement.style = 'background:'+ colors[nextSelectedColor]; // update the element background with selected color
}
```

You can also replay the same codes or update: it here is the [full replayed code in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o29uvd8t/1/) which i made to make it more easy.

Comment: thank you so much, this is what I was attempting to do:  i have a follow-up question - What if I want to load the div box colors from an sql database vs. simply loading them blue on page load?

Comment: @genuis you are welcome, if my answer helped you do not hesitate to mark it **as solved** and **to add +1** to share with others please.

Answering to your question: i see that you want colors to be retrieved from DB (means dynamically by request/response) right? if this is the case then there is a lot of manners to make it, you can use native js [XHMLHttpRequests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or using library as [Jquery Ajax Requests](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or using any known framework services as Angular Http Client